# how to use a picked image as background image in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, statefulwidget

I've used file_picker library so the user can select his favorite image and then use it as the background image in my application. Thing is, I can't cast it correctly. Here's some code:

```
 floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              final result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(type: FileType.any, allowMultiple: false);
              if (result != null) {
                var fileBytes = result.files.first.bytes;
                if (fileBytes != null) {
                  blogimage = Image.memory(fileBytes);
                  setState(() {});
                }
              }
            },
            tooltip: 'Select Image',
            child: Icon(Icons.select_all),
          ),
```

In the above code, I'm getting the image.
and I'm trying to use `blogimage` as my background image.
I've already tried using containers but failed. This is the code I used:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        decoration: (blogimage != null)? BoxDecoration(image: DecorationImage(image: blogimage)): null,
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(widget.title),
          ),
.....
```

Got the error: Expected a value of type 'ImageProvider', but got one of type 'Image'.

Any ideas?
Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, If you want to get the bytes from the selected image you are missing one argument

```
final result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(type: FileType.any, allowMultiple: false, withData: true);
```

**withData: true** Will give you the bytes from the selected image.

If you do not set it to true **result.files.first.bytes** will be null.

Secondly, Why declare blogImage as a Image type?

Use Uint8List type instead and use MemoryImage(blogImage) in your DecorationImage

```
class FilePickerTest extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FilePickerTestState createState() => _FilePickerTestState();
}

class _FilePickerTestState extends State<FilePickerTest> {
  Uint8List? blogImage;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          final result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(type: FileType.any, allowMultiple: false, withData: true);
          if (result != null) {
            blogImage = result.files.first.bytes;
            if (blogImage != null) {
              setState(() {});
            }
          }
        },
        tooltip: 'Select Image',
        child: Icon(Icons.select_all),
      ),
      body: Container(
        decoration: (blogImage != null) ? BoxDecoration(image: DecorationImage(image: MemoryImage(blogImage!))) : null,
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(widget.title),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are providing an image widget, while the code requires something that will provide an image. Like when you use image, you can implement it like

```
Image(
  image:AssetImage("")//This is the image provider
)
```

So instead of passing the widget, we will pass the provider, which in this case is MemoryImage

```
                  blogimage = MemoryImage(fileBytes);
```

Hope it helps. Also, in the decoration of this image, you might need to use properties

```
Container(
        decoration: (blogimage != null)? BoxDecoration(image: DecorationImage(image: blogimage,fit:BoxFit.cover)): null,
   constraints:BoxConstraints.expand()

)
```

Answer (score 1):

withData: true if you want to have the file loaded into memory in advance
and if not set then always return FilePickerResult.files.bytes null value

```
FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(type: FileType.any, allowMultiple: false,withData: true);
      if (result != null) {
        var fileBytes = result.files.first.bytes;
        if (fileBytes != null) {
          blogimage = fileBytes;
          setState(() {});
        }
      }
```

Show an image with the ImageProvider MemoryImage thats given an Uint8list

```
Container(
    decoration: (blogimage != null)? BoxDecoration(image: DecorationImage(image: MemoryImage(blogimage))): null,
    child: Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
```